# Issues with the Grid (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: xamarin, grid, xamarin.forms

I am using the following code to make the impression that a solid color is masked with a square:

```
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var maskSide = 196;

    var grid = new Grid {ColumnSpacing = 0, RowSpacing = 0};
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength((App.ScreenHeight - maskSide) / 2, GridUnitType.Absolute) });
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(maskSide, GridUnitType.Absolute) });
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength((App.ScreenWidth - maskSide) / 2, GridUnitType.Absolute) });
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(maskSide, GridUnitType.Absolute) });
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

    grid.Children.Add(new BoxView { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, BackgroundColor = Color.Lime }, 0, 0);
    grid.Children.Add(new BoxView { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, BackgroundColor = Color.Lime }, 0, 1);
    grid.Children.Add(new BoxView { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, BackgroundColor = Color.Lime }, 0, 2);

    grid.Children.Add(new BoxView { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, BackgroundColor = Color.Lime }, 1, 0);
    grid.Children.Add(new BoxView { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent }, 1, 1);
    grid.Children.Add(new BoxView { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, BackgroundColor = Color.Lime }, 1, 2);

    grid.Children.Add(new BoxView { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, BackgroundColor = Color.Lime }, 2, 0);
    grid.Children.Add(new BoxView { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, BackgroundColor = Color.Lime }, 2, 1);
    grid.Children.Add(new BoxView { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, BackgroundColor = Color.Lime }, 2, 2);

    grid.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
    grid.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;

    Content = grid;
}
```

I am setting device dimensions in Droid's MainActivity's OnCreate like this :

```
App.ScreenWidth = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
App.ScreenHeight = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
```

Here is the result:

[image]

However there are two issues with that:

As you can see, there are two issues:

1. For some reason, the masking square isn't located exactly in the middle.
2. There is a one (or maybe two) pixel gap between the last items in both, vertical and horizontal stacks.

I cannot understand, what is the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: IF you switch to xaml and use some designers like Gorilla Player then your life will be much easier

Comment: how is this relevant to the problem?

Comment: It does not , but just a tip for free :)

Answer (score 1):

`Grid` can take care of this for you

```
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(maskSide, GridUnitType.Absolute) });
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(maskSide, GridUnitType.Absolute) });
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
```

Comment: now vertical spacing line disappeared, the horizontal is still there

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze is it centered? I'm not seeing any lines on my side. What version are you running?

Comment: yes, the centering problem disappeared. I am using `XF 2.0.0.6482`. When tested on Xamarin Android Player emulator (Lollipop 5.1"), there are no more spacing lines. however, when testing on my Nexus 5x (Marshmallow), there clearly still is a problem with the vertical spacing line.

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze Did you copy the above code? I find it weird that one line would disappear. I'm using `2.1.0.6529` and no lines appear. You would need to show more code for me to figure out why the line is appearing.

Comment: yes, i used your code. there is no more code, that's it.